# Xcode server at Xcode 9 ; Bot XCUITest fails: 'Test target encountered an error (Early unexpected exit.....)

Tags: xcode9, xcode-server, xcuitest

We have set up continuous environment at xcode9 at dedicated mac.Xcode-server is set up on that machine and bot has been created to build project and execute tests.
Build required cocoapods , hence pre-integration script is also used.

Now, when bot starts UI tests, the app installs at simulator , but doesn't launch and eventually consoles log following error : 
*Test Target 'xx' encountered an error (Early unexpected exit , operation never finished bootsrapping - no restart will be attempted)*

On investigation of 'Raw build logs' we found Main Thread Checker error shows up with firebase warning.

> Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState] PID: 34330, TID: 355611, Thread name: (none), Queue name: NSOperationQueue 0x600000239dc0 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED), QoS: 0 Backtrace:

Had mitigated this issue by unchecking Edit Scheme->Test/Debug->Main Thread Checker under diagnostic section , while running tests locally.

Does same error showing up at continuous environment means that we have to pass the unchecking of Main Thread Checker as an argument ? Or is there something we are missing ?

Kindly help.

Comment: Did you figure out the problem?

Comment: We have set up a pipeline to generate .xctestrun artifact for simulator and run XCUITests at generated artifact.                                                                 
xcodebuild clean build-for-testing CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= PROVISIONING_PROFILE= -workspace 'xxxx.xcworkspace' -scheme 'xxxx' -sdk iphonesimulator -ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES ENABLE_TESTABILITY=YES -configuration Release For XCUITest run :xcodebuild test-without-building "$testClass" -xctestrun "$artifactName" -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=latest' -resultBundlePath $testReportDir